# Problems saving Django ORM object with a many to one relationship

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```py
class Answer(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    question_key = models.IntegerField()
    answer_index = models.IntegerField()
    user_session = models.ForeignKey(
        UserSession, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="answers"
    )
```

`user_session` cannot be `None` and I'd love to keep it that way.

This is how I'm trying to save an `Answer` object:

```py
    answer = Answer(
        question_key=question_key,
        answer_index=answer_index,
        user_session=user_session,
        order=answer_order,
    )
    answer.save()
```

But I get the error: `ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user_session'.`

My research suggests that I need to save the Answer object prior to adding the `user_session` to it. However, I can't do that if I would like to preserve the not null constraint on the Answer model.

Is there a better way to solve this or should I just allow `Answer.user_session` to be nullable?

Comment: You will first need to save the `user_session`. So `user_session.save()` and then `answer = Answer(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't save the `UserSession` object (`user_session`), hence the error; it's a Many-to-One relationship so you can directly use the `UserSession` object as the value of `user_session` field while creating an instance of `Answer`.

So first save the `UserSession` object and then refer it directly in `Answer` model instantiation.

For example:

```
user_session.save()

answer = Answer(
    question_key=question_key,
    answer_index=answer_index,
    user_session=user_session,
    order=answer_order,
)
answer.save()
```

Also you're not doing anything after instantiating `Answer`, so you can use `create` directly:

```
answer = Answer.objects.create(
    question_key=question_key,
    answer_index=answer_index,
    user_session=user_session,
    order=answer_order,
)
```

Comment: That works thanks. I am actually doing something else with `answer` after which is why I didn't use `create` directly.

Answer (score 2):

That error is not about unsaved Answer, but about unsaved user session. You need to save all related objects (in that case that is user_session) before referencing it in other objects as foreign key, because object can not be referenced when it does not have an ID (and it does not have it until saved to database)